# Whats wrong with my MS Access Update Query?

Tags: c#, ms-access

Here is my Query:

```
string Select = "Update DC set Password = '" + txtPass.Text + "' WHERE ID ="+Convert.ToInt32(cbxDocs.SelectedIndex + 1);
con = new OleDbConnection();
this.readconfile = new ReadConfigFile();
con.ConnectionString = this.readconfile.ConfigString(ConfigFiles.ProjectConfigFile);
con.Open();
cmd = new OleDbCommand(Select, con);
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I don't know what is wrong but it gives me an error message that "Syntax error in UPDATE STATEMENT".
I have two fields in my table 'DC' ID and Password, nothing else.

Comment: Use placeholders. These clean up the query and avoid subtle errors that can be caused - like the password containing a `'`. Also, make sure "password" or "id" aren't reserved words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PASSWORD` [is a reserved word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sql-reserved-words-b899948b-0e1c-4b56-9622-a03f8f07cfc8#bmdaidxsqln_p). Enclose it in square brackets like `[Password]`, so your query should start like:

```cs
"Update DC set [Password]....
```

*Consider using parameterized query, this will save you from [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)*.

Answer (score 0):

I think u don't need the ' on ur query and Password is reserved in almost every ddb.
And you could use parameters to avoid the concat with the +
Ex.

```
string pass = TxtPass.Text;
int s = cbxDocs.SelectedIndex+1;
string Select = "Update DC set Password = @a WHERE ID = @o";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Select, conn);
cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@a", pass);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@o", s);
//everything else....
```

Comment: thanks for your help that is something new for me.I will keep in mind.